# Sequence with only comma and newline is valid but not without new line

Tags: scala

In Scala following is a valid syntax

```
val seqWithCommaAndNewline = Seq(
        ,
    )
```

But this is not:

```
val seqWithComma = Seq(,)
```

Here is a test script to check this fast:

```
val seqWithCommaAndNewline = Seq(
        ,
    )

println(seqWithCommaAndNewline)

val seqWithComma = Seq(,)

println(seqWithComma)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the spec for the feature, trailing comma is ignored only for bracket on next line.

Comment: Corresponding reference in the spec: https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/01-lexical-syntax.html

Comment: To say more, the reasoning was it was about doing line edits, commenting lines, etc, with minimal deltas, so it was deemed to be line-oriented.

Comment: Yea, I just wish I can add trailing commas like python, that would be nice to reduced deltas.